# How to show focus rectangle when the item in list is selected in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, styles

I want to show the focus  rectangle of item when it is selected.

Because IsFocusedProperty is read-only, I can't do it with XAML.

How can I show the focused rectangle...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The focus rectangle is part of Keyboard Focus, and is displayed when a user uses the Keyboard to set focus to an Input element.  I tested out manually setting Keyboard Focus (using Keyboard.Focus()), but it doesn't seem to work.

So I'd recommend creating a custom style that will simulate the focus rect when the ListBoxItem is selected.  I came up with the style below that seems to work.  It matches the focus rect's dash array so that it doesn't look strange when the real focus rect is displayed.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Grid>
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
      <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This also gives you a lot more control over how your ListBoxItem is displayed in general.  You could easily adapt this to other list types as well (ListViewItem, etc.)